# How to transform a specific timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm trying to transform timestamp to date:

Example:

**this is ok**

```
$ts = 1456172110000 / 1000; 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $ts)->format("Y-m-d H:i:ss");
echo $date;
Result: 2016-02-22 20:15:1010
```

**But this no**

```
$ts = 1495730996979 / 1000; 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $ts)->format("Y-m-d H:i:ss");
echo $date;
```

Result: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean

How can I solve this problem?

I want to save this timeStamp in Mysql and retrieve as a formatted date

Thank you

Comment: But why `ss` in your output format?

Comment: Answer it @MarkBaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`U` mask in createFromFormat() needs to be an integer value, or one that contains no digits other than zero after the decimal

Either cast to an integer:

```
$ts = (int) (1495730996979 / 1000); 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $ts)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $date;
```

Or modify your mask with `u` for the fractional seconds

```
$ts = 1495730996979 / 1000;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("U.u", $ts)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $date;
```